# Mathematica Rewriting Circle Equation

Tags: math, geometry, wolfram-mathematica

I have a circle with the expression:

x^2+y^2+10x-14y-7=0

I need to find the radius and the coordinates to the center of the circle using Wolfram Mathematica; in [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/x%5E%7B2%7D%2By%5E%7B2%7D%2B10%5Ccdot%20x-14%5Ccdot%20y-7%3D0) it tells me to rewrite the expression in the form of the standard eclipse equation.

I know that the answer should be c=(x+5)^2 + (y-7)^2 = 81, so the radius is sqrt(81) = 9 ...

How is this achievable in Mathematica (I'm very new to this...)?

Thanks and best regards (-:

Comment: Related link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20051/how-do-i-get-my-equation-to-have-the-form-x-a2-y-b2-z-c2-d-0/20159

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
SolveAlways[{x^2 + y^2 + 10 x - 14 y - 7 == (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 - r^2}, {x, y}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Solve[{
 CoefficientList[x^2 + y^2 + 10 x - 14 y - 7, {x, y}]
  ==
  CoefficientList[(x - xc)^2 + (y - yc)^2 -  r^2, {x, y} ],r>0}
 , {xc, yc, r}]
```

> {{xc -> -5, yc -> 7, r -> 9}}